# How do i Pass a set<int> var to a function?

Tags: c++11, stl, depth-first-search

The function dfs() in this program operates upon the set A & array C. The program works fine when set A and int C[MAX] are declared global. But when i try to use this program t number of times, the set A and C are initialized with previous test cases's values, which gives wrong output. How can i make this program to accept new values in A & C for every next case. Note: This program is intended to find if the graph with n number of nodes and m number of edges is bipartite or not.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
   using namespace std;

  const int MAX=1000000; // maximum number of vertices

   int dfs(int x,const set<int>& A,int C[]){
for(int y:A[x]){
    if(C[y]==C[x])return 0;// this means the graph is not bipartite
    if(C[y]==0){
        if(C[x]==1) C[y]=2;
        else C[y]=1;
        dfs(y,A,C);
        return 1;
    }
}
   }

int main(){

int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    set<int> A[MAX];// Here, i declare set<int> A and Int C[MAX] in local          scope
    int C[MAX];

    // Passing set<int> A and int C[] to dfs()..

    int res = dfs(i,A,int C);    
 }
```

If i change my code to something like above. I get the following error.

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int dfs(int, const std::set<int>&, int*)':
prog.cpp:8:16: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'const std::set<int>' and 'int')          
 for(int y:A[x]){
```

Comment: any reason not to use a std::array or std::vector instead of a C array?

Comment: No, the issue is with set<int> A.

Comment: I know this is just a general advice. you obviously can use c++. there is no reason for C arrays. Also: can you clean up your code and only leave in the parts which are important to the question? What happens if you just pass the set as parameter into the function? what are the errors? etc.

Comment: @Hayt , this the error i am getting if set<int> A is declared in local scope.

Comment: The issue is, your function is expecting a `std::set<>`. `A` is an array of sets though. So the types do not match. Also a std::set<> has no operator[]. You probably want to have a `std::set<int>[]` as parameter.

Comment: Now runtime error ! @Hayt , Could you please edit this code ?

Comment: You can debug through the code and locate your runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

According to the c++ doc, [set - C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) there is not such `operator[]` in `std::set<>`so your `for(int y:A[x])` is wrong. You cannot call `A[x]`.

I'd recommend to use an `vector` or some other container meeting your requirement instead of a `std::set`